# Mirror and image vertically for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been looking through some possible solution for this question, and i have found out that you can use the PIL library, but i wanted to ask if there is a possible solution by using a for loop.

Here's what I've tried:

```
! git clone https://github.com/carldjapardi/Trial-

import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow
from PIL import Image

path = "/content/Trial-/chaplin.jpg"
image = Image.open(path).convert('L')
mat_image = np.array(image) #turn to np array 
m, n = mat_image.shape #img shape, m is the height, n is the width

mat_image_reversed = mat_image

for i in range(n):
  reversed_column = []
  for j in range(m-1, -1, -1):
    reversed_column.append(mat_image_reversed[i][j])
  mat_image_reversed[i] = reversed_column

imshow(mat_image_reversed, cmap = 'gray')
```

The problem is i keep getting a:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-84670325c66b> in <module>()

----> 7   mat_image_reversed[i] = reversed_column

ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 394 to array axis with dimension 700
```

i tried replacing it with`mat_image_reversed[j] = reversed_column`, but it gave the same error

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
…
for i in range(m):
  reversed_column = []
  for j in range(n-1, -1, -1):
…
```

But I guess what you need is:

```
mat_image_reversed = np.flip(mat_image,0)
```

or

```
mat_image_reversed = np.flip(mat_image,1)
```

accordingly.